# how to get both user id and password of logged-in user in Jenkins to pass to build jobs?

Tags: svn, jenkins, ant

I am executing ANT script in Jenkins. As I need to commit a file in SVN, i am using "exec" task of ANT by passing svn commands as arguments. It needs username and password as arguments to commit the file. By providing the predefined credentials in Jenkins, this task is working fine. But i need to pass the credentials of the logged-in user in Jenkins. I got the current user id but unable to get its password.

Comment: Jenkins doesn't have a way of exposing user passwords in plaintext, for obvious reasons. However, you can create a parameterized job and add a string parameter for the user to manually enter their password when they start a build.

Comment: Note that this is NOT a good solution, though, since it will reveal users' passwords in the console, and parameters aren't handled in a secure way in Jenkins at all. Only do this if you do not care about security at all.

Comment: Instead of adding a string parameter, add a password parameter